Webscrapping magento website. API calls with 200 empty response when no timestamp specified
Help on magento website for scrapping purpose
I’m kinda new so sorry if some terms seem weird.
I am trying for a personnal context to scrap data from the website Prolians https://www.prolians.fr/ which uses magento and cloudflare.
The thing is some pieces of data are dynamically rendered. And a section of the website (Equivalent products for each products)
I found that there is an api call called: getequivalentproducts
Example for a product (gant de manutention handlite 200g opsialp) :
link of the product :
https://www.prolians.fr/gant-de-manutention-handlite-200g-opsialp702708.html
the api call :
https://www.prolians.fr/equivalentproducts/widget/getequivalentproducts?sku=P702708&_=1726650753165
so sku can be found in the product page url and the _ is a timestamp if I’m not missunderstanding
when I copy paste the url of the api call in postman it returns me the json which contains the html part I want. but if I remove the _, it returns me nothing
Then I created a script to query the Api with the timestamp which is dinamically generated and once again nothing happen. I also tried to change the timestamp adding or removing just one on numbers like that : 1726651065756 and the reponse is empty still code 200 tho
timestamp = int(time.time() * 1000)
I don’t really know what to do from here I tried adding some more headers but this is not working.
Maybe there is a security and to limit the botting but I can only access data from the page product I visited with my browser before
Thanks in advance for the help guys :slight_smile:
I've tried generating a fresh timestamp in milliseconds for every request using Python to ensure accuracy

The timestamp is not necessary, you just need the correct header (x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest):
import requests

params = {
    'sku': 'P702708'
}

headers = {
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

url = "https://www.prolians.fr/equivalentproducts/widget/getequivalentproducts"
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

print(response.text)

*The reason you are getting a correct response when using a timestamp from the browser is probably because the server is caching the requests.
